Scheduling a task with cron
I have digital signage software on raspberry Pi 4. It needs restarting 3 times a day to update menus. I have been looking into Cron jobs for this. I don't have any experience with Linux terminals and I have fallen at the first hurdle. After struggling to navigate the terminal, I have tried launch the program (posterbooking)to see if I have the correct path before attempting to configure a cron job. So far, I have typed in this path - cd usr/share/applications/posterbooking.desktop
which I got from here - 
It would not boot. My eventual plan was to schedule the raspberry pi to restart 3 times a day with posterbooking starting automatically on startup. Any advise on this will be very appreciated.

I can't comment but I really recommend you to use the Linux terminal.
Your question is similar to this one. I think it might help you
You would just have to add this line :
0 */8 * * * /sbin/reboot

This entry will perform a reboot every 8h
If you want a specific schedule like doing the first reboot at 7:30am you should add these lines instead of the previous one:
30 7 * * * /sbin/reboot
30 10 * * * /sbin/reboot
30 12 * * * /sbin/reboot

I invite you to use the command man crontab to explore all the possibilites

Yes it is a script to restart the posterbooking program 3 times a day that I need.

"My eventual plan was to schedule the Raspberry Pi to restart 3 times a day with posterbooking starting automatically on startup". Doing a sudo reboot every 8 hours would allow you to do that. I updated my answer.

Is it possible to choose the time? For example, 7.30am, 10.30am and 12.30pm?

I've updated my answer according to your question
